# IOS- move multiple images in upward direction vertically

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, core-animation

i am new to IOS programming. i want to move multiple images in upward direction so that the images go upward and then comes back from bottom of screen. so at the moment i am successfully moving one image to the upward direction. but i dont know how can i add and move multiple images to upward direction

images names which i want to show:
image01
image02
image03
image04
image05
image06

here is my code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 560, 320, 100)];
    [self.myImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image01.jpeg"]];
    [self.view addSubview:self.myImageView];
    [self setImages];
}
-(void)setImages
{
    for(int i=1;i<5;i++)
    {

        float height = self.myImageView.center.y-0.15;
        if(height<-130){

            height=self.view.frame.size.height;
        }
        self.myImageView.center = CGPointMake (self.myImageView.center.x, height);
        NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Height is %f",height]);
    }

    [self performSelector:@selector(setImages) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.03];
}
```

Comment: Rather than re-asking the same question, I'd recommend editing the original with your new details.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it completely wrong.

You need:

1) scrollView;

2) separate ImageViews for each image as subviews of scrollViews with proper frames.

3) set proper contentSize of scrollView

4) scroll images by changing scrollView's content offset with animation.

Comment: i don't think so you have undertstand my question. i dont need a scroll view on my screen. i want to move all the images up with animation. the user dont have to click on the screen. its like i am using this screen in the background so that images are going up continuously.